# Im trying to generate a unique hash for all the users

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, database-design

I'm trying to generate a unique hash for all the users in the Database; Here is my code:

```
<?php
include("php/connect.php");


$sql = "SELECT id FROM user";


while ($id = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))) {

    $new_hash = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO user (hash) VALUE ('$new_hash') WHERE id = $id['id']";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);


}

?>
```

Every time I run it, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: MD5 is really not worth using. At the absolute least use [SHA256](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2).

Comment: Read this the way you got is not codeigniter way http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: Don't you need `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this query:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO user (hash) VALUE ('$new_hash') WHERE id = $id['id']";
```

[`INSERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) doesn't use a [`WHERE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimization.html) clause, [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) does, as does [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

However, I don't know why you're wanting to do that. Using a column set to AUTO_INCREMENT should be ample to have a unique id.

Yet, if that is what you want to do, then you will need to use one of the methods shown above.

- [`mysqli_error($conn)`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) by the way, would have thrown you an syntax error about this.

I.e.:

```
if(!$sql2){ 

  echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean here is to update the `hash` field of the `user` table. If you don't really care what the hashes are so long as they're quasi-random then do this:

```
UPDATE user SET hash=SHA2(UUID())
```

If you want them cryptographically random, completely unpredictable, you'll need to use a better generator of random data than the [`UUID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) function.